# Run a service in async mode in Ansible

Tags: asynchronous, ansible, hashicorp-vault

I want to run Hashicorp Vault service using Ansible shell module but in async mode.

`vault server -config=config.hcl`

Otherwise the tasks after it doesn't execute and terminal gets stuck. How to do that?

I saw there's an async module in Ansible. Will it work in this case? But it requires us to specify some time for which the service will run in background but i want to execute it in background, infinitely. Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way to run Vault using Ansible. What you should do instead is use Ansible to set up a service on the host machine that will run Vault. If your host is running systemd, this service definition might work:

```
[Unit]
Description=a tool for managing secrets
Documentation=https://vaultproject.io/docs/
After=network.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty={{ vault_config_path }}

[Service]
User=vault
Group=vault
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vault server -config={{ vault_config_path }}
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill --signal HUP $MAINPID
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYSLOG CAP_IPC_LOCK
Capabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK+ep
SecureBits=keep-caps
NoNewPrivileges=yes
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where `vault_config_path` is an Ansible variable holding the path to the `config.hcl` - you can of course alter this to your heart's content.

Having installed this service definition (into `/etc/systemd/system/vault.service`), you can then start the Vault service with an Ansible task like:

```
- name: Enable Vault service
  service:
    name: vault
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```